# Extract Text from a string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a string which contains :

```
navigation pane or double clicking folders in the details pane.

Navigating the folder structure
-------------------------------
symbol will expand or collapse folders in the navigation pane
```

I want to extract text only "Navigating the folder structure"

I have tried with preg_match_all but unable to handle starting point which is a new line.

I also tried with strpos but unable to do with new line as starting point.

Comment: Did you try `strpos`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php

Comment: I tried that but how to handle new line in strpos ?

Comment: so what's the condition do you judge which string should be extract? the following "`------------------`"?

Comment: It can be started from a new line and should be ending at --------, so as per question's string. it will be Navigating  the folder structure. But I need to do this dynamic so what ever the text it contains that should be extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `strpos` to find the line breaks, and `substr` to extract the text between the first and second line break.  This text includes the dashes (`-`) so I included a `str_replace` to remove them.

```
$string = 'navigation pane or double clicking folders in the details pane.

    Navigating the folder structure
    -------------------------------
    symbol will expand or collapse folders in the navigation pane';

$position1 = strpos($string, "\n");
$position2 = strpos($string, "\n",$position1);

$extracted = str_replace("-","",substr($string, $position1, $position2));

echo $extracted;
```

This will print the desired text

Comment: Well the text "Navigating the folder structure" is not a constant it can be anything.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan ok i updated it, similar logic as before but a bit different

Comment: Well, I think I missed some details. I have a file in which I have multiple text of above pattern so I want all that pattern based text should be extracted. By the way, above code is not working.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan you should do a better job asking the question then.  Also, I have a PHP server running on my machine and I tested this answer and the other one and they both work.

Comment: Hmmm ok let me check again.

Comment: Ah, I got the clue. In fact you are assuming that string contains only these 3,4 lines. while I have a file having 3000 lines.

Comment: I did it with small fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) -

```
$new =  explode("\n", $str);
var_dump($new[2]);
```

Comment: Nopes. not working

Comment: works for me with the above string .

Comment: @jitendrapurohit worked for me